# replacing self->isa because of deprecation

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, class

I just installed Xcode 4.6 and now I'm getting new errors in an ancient code I manage.

The compiler complains that "Direct access to objective-c's isa being deprecated in favor of object_setClass() and object_getClass()" and th e project won't build.

So please tell me, is:

```
object_setClass(self, [CustomClass class]);
```

the appropriate replacement of:

```
self->isa = [CustomClass class];
```

Thank you!

Comment: xcode is an IDE, it doesn't deprecate anything. the newer objc SDKs do

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Accessing `isa` has been deprecated for some time, the tools just didn't tell you this. Notably, it's been deprecated for at least as long as tagged pointers have existed in obj-c.

And yes, `object_setClass()` is the appropriate replacement.

That said, why do you even need this? It's extremely rare that replacing the class of an object is appropriate, and the only valid case I can think of is when you're trying to dynamically subclass a class in order to inject new behavior into individual instances without modifying the class as a whole (which is, of course, something you probably don't need to do).

Comment: thank you for the confirmation. yes, I agree the design of this code is really weird. not my doing.

Comment: I would light that code on fire and run away screaming if I encountered it in the wild.

Comment: I just found such code (`array->isa      = _JKArrayClass;`) in a library I was told to implement. (oh, it's part of JSONKit from 2011)